# linq how to process each element?

Tags: c#, linq

I can never remember. How do i process each element in a string? I want to write

```
stringblah.Split('/n', Split('\n', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .Each(s=>s.Trim());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx)?

```
var items = stringblah.Split(new[] {'\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                      .Select(s => s.Trim());

// ...

foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always make your own extension method:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (T element in source) action(element);
    }
}
```

However, I would warn that most people would say you shouldn't do this. Using a traditional foreach loop is considered the better practice.

Comment: Clearly not what he is asking, `ForEach(s=>s.Trim())` would have no effect